# Firebase Failed to initialize a certificate credential. Caused by: "Incorrect padding" when deploy flask in app-engine

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine, flask

help me,
i try to make app with flask and deploy to heroku with, but i have a free credit in gcp so i try deploy to app engine, but i have error

> credentials.Certificate({    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 98, in **init**      raise ValueError('Failed to initialize a certificate credential. '  ValueError: Failed to initialize a certificate credential. Caused by: "Incorrect padding"

in my app engine wichis work fine in my heroku

```
from firebase_admin import initialize_app, firestore, credentials
from os import environ

cred = credentials.Certificate({
    "type": environ["TYPE"],
    "project_id": environ["PROJECT_ID"],
    "private_key_id": environ["PRIVATE_KEY_ID"],
    "private_key": environ["PRIVATE_KEY"].replace('\\n', '\n'),
    "client_email": environ["CLIENT_EMAIL"],
    "client_id": environ["CLIENT_ID"],
    "auth_uri": environ["AUTH_URI"],
    "token_uri": environ["TOKEN_URI"],
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": environ["AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"],
    "client_x509_cert_url": environ["CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL"]
})
```

my yaml file like this

```
runtime: python38
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :80 app:app

env_variables:
  FLASK_RUN_PORT: 80
  FLASK_DEBUG: TRUE
  TYPE: service_account
  PROJECT_ID: cendek-url
  // my firebase credential key //
```

Comment: How are you setting the credential in the yaml?

Comment: What if you hardcode with three single quotes `''' key definition '''` in your `aaa.py` file?

Comment: @JossBaron i use env_variables like the guide in docs here [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref), and thanks i will try to use three quotes.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work this?